# When should we use NativeMemory.Alloc() in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

.NET6/C# introduced `NativeMemory` class, but I did not get when we should use `NativeMemory.Alloc()` instead of normal array instantiation(`new T[]`). My questions are:

1. Which area on memory does `NativeMemory.Alloc()` populate objects? Does the method populate objects in managed heap?
2. What kind of situation should we use `NativeMemory.Alloc()` on behalf of `new T[]`?

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.nativememory?view=net-6.0

Comment: Just a guess: I think they added this to have a more OS-independent API for allocating/freeing native memory that is used together with P/Invoke calls. Previously, we already had `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` and `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()`, but these are named after the corresponding WinApi functions, and don't really fit into an OS-independent framework.

Comment: History [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/33244), they created a new type in order to break away from Marshal class practices of using IntPtr.  The void* return forces the programmer to use `unsafe` in their code.  Usage is otherwise identical, you'd allocate native memory to pass to code written in a native language like C.  Which is rare, you'll know it when you need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it's a "thin wrapper over the C `malloc` API." So if I'm recalling correctly it would allocate memory on the unmanaged heap.

As for the second question, I can't really think of any specific scenarios (save for some edge-cases) where that would be useful (though I'm sure they exist) in .NET where one wouldn't already be using C/C++. That aside though, I suppose one would use this where speed is absolutely paramount (such as rendering).

It's just been added so that we'd have the option to use C/C++ like memory management.

Comment: One very good aspect of it is that there is an AlignedAlloc() version. For the cases where you need as much performance you can get, aligning your data in memory can help. I recently used it to allocate data for a method that used SIMD, it worked on four 256 bit registers each iteration. Aligning the data to cache line size had a performance impact.