# Marshal vs NativeMemory

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management

I'm writing a virtual machine in C# and I'm using Marshal class to allocate and free memory for example:

```
public ulong Allocate(int allocationSize) = (ulong)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(allocationSize);

public void Free(ulong address)
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)address);
}
```

It has come to my attention that there also exists a class `NativeMemory` that also has `Alloc` and `Free` methods. Are they doing the same thing? And if not when should each one be used.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70477685/1997232).

Comment: Why do you even need to do this? What are you doing that needs native memory?